# NPM can't install appjs. Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'

Tags: linux, node.js, npm

I installed node.js and npm already, but when I try to install appjs I get this error:

```
zephlon@zephlon-T5254:~$ npm install appjs

node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/ini.js:32:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
```

I get similar errors on any attempt to install `graceful-fs`.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

P.S.: Here's the link to the appjs website:
http://appjs.org/

Comment: It is not related to appjs. It is a problem with your npm. You can get better answer with changing topic.

Comment: Ok. I added npm to the title and the tags.

Comment: And you can ask at nodejs mailing list to get answer:)

Answer (score 13):

use the following script to solve this

```
git clone git://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm/script
chmod +x bootstrap
sudo ./bootstrap
```

Comment: Did you mean `npm/scripts?` Also, are you referring to the npm folder in the home folder?

Comment: I got the following error: `bash: ./sudo: No such file or directory
`

Comment: it should be sudo ./install.sh and cd npm/scripts

Comment: it's now in `npm/script/bootstrap`

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem when trying to install anything with npm on a Ubuntu LTS12.04 vps, and I solved it with

```
sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt-get install npm
```

You may also want to run npm install *_*_  inside of /usr/lib/nodejs

Answer (score 1):

With the [node.js PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/+packages) from Chris Lea, `npm` is integrated in the `nodejs` package [since version 0.10](https://chrislea.com/2013/03/15/upgrading-from-node-js-0-8-x-to-0-10-0-from-my-ppa/). Works with 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the graceful-fs problem. After seeing this message when trying to update npm:

```
Error: npm doesn't work with node v0.10.0
Required: node@0.6 || 0.7 || 0.8
```

I used the n module to switch to **0.8.22** stable release of node. I was able to install graceful-fs, request, and other modules after that. Probably not the best solution, but none of the other solutions here worked for me.